# How to create and export a table in Stata?

Tags: stata, export-to-pdf, export-to-word

I have some survey data for respondents' incomes, stocks, bonds, and retirement accounts for the years 2000 to 2011. Each respondent is also divided into one of 4 groups. For each group, I want to create an annual percent change table for each of the variables. I also want to export and display this table in Word or as a PDF. How would I go about doing that?

Below is the code I have so far. While I can display the table within Stata, I'm not sure how to export it, rename the variables, or make the table look nicer. Any help is appreciated.

```
//dataset imported here


collapse (mean) stocks bonds income retacct, by(group year)


foreach x of varlist stocks - retacct{

bysort group (year): gen d\_\`x' = (\`x'- \`x'\[\_n-1\]) / \`x'\[\_n-1\] \* 100
}



list year d_* if group == 1, sep(0)

list year d_* if group == 2, sep(0)

list year d_* if group == 3, sep(0)

list year d_* if group == 4, sep(0)
```

[Here is what the table output currently looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbEGE.png)

Comment: Cross-posted and answered at https://www.reddit.com/r/stata/comments/1av6z0c/how_to_make_and_export_a_table/  As in your previous post, please note that flagging cross-posting is good practice anywhere. Not doing so is often considered anti-social.